# How to write a program to record sound and write it to the SD card?

Tags: c, eclipse, multithreading, stm32, fatfs

I am using a STM32L476G_EVAL board and Eclipse(C language). I need to write a program which can record sound and write the obtained samples of the sound to the SD card. I have two separate codes, one for recording and reproducing the sound which uses DFSDM HAL API, the other for writing a vector to the SD Card in RTOS mode. I have made a new source code with two threads, one for recording the sound, the other for writing to the sd card. The problem is that the threading, for a certain reason, does not work, it stops after the first write procedure to the sd card. I'm guessing that it has something to do with fatfs and the threading, as I tried multithreading with fatfs and far simpler function(LED toggle) and it also did not work. Probably I'm missing some kind of information, as I am kind of new in this field. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

```
#define SDMMC1              ((SDMMC_TypeDef *) SDMMC1_BASE)

#include "main.h"
#include "main1.h"
#include "main2.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "ff.h"
#include "pthread.h"

/** @addtogroup STM32L4xx_HAL_Examples
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup DFSDM_AudioRecord
  * @{
  */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define SaturaLH(N, L, H) (((N)<(L))?(L):(((N)>(H))?(H):(N)))
#define SizeBuff 2048 //macro variable for the size of the buffers
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
DFSDM_Channel_HandleTypeDef  DfsdmLeftChannelHandle;
DFSDM_Channel_HandleTypeDef  DfsdmRightChannelHandle;
DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef   DfsdmLeftFilterHandle;
DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef   DfsdmRightFilterHandle;
DMA_HandleTypeDef            hLeftDma;
DMA_HandleTypeDef            hRightDma;
SAI_HandleTypeDef            SaiHandle;
DMA_HandleTypeDef            hSaiDma;

FATFS SDFatFs;  /* File system object for SD card logical drive */
FIL MyFile;     /* File object */
char SDPath[4]; /* SD card logical drive path */

AUDIO_DrvTypeDef            *audio_drv;
int32_t                      LeftRecBuff[2048];
int32_t                      RightRecBuff[2048];
int16_t                      PlayBuff[4096];
uint32_t                     DmaLeftRecHalfBuffCplt  = 0;
uint32_t                     DmaLeftRecBuffCplt      = 0;
uint32_t                     DmaRightRecHalfBuffCplt = 0;
uint32_t                     DmaRightRecBuffCplt     = 0;
uint32_t                     PlaybackStarted         = 0;
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void DFSDM_Init(void);
static void Playback_Init(void);
static void SD_Thread(void const *argument);
static void Audio_Thread(void const *argument);

osThreadId AudioThreadHandle, SDThreadHandle;

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L4xx HAL library initialization:
       - Configure the Flash prefetch
       - Systick timer is configured by default as source of time base, but user 
         can eventually implement his proper time base source (a general purpose 
         timer for example or other time source), keeping in mind that Time base 
         duration should be kept 1ms since PPP_TIMEOUT_VALUEs are defined and 
         handled in milliseconds basis.
       - Set NVIC Group Priority to 4
       - Low Level Initialization
     */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock to have a frequency of 80 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Configure LED1 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED1);
  BSP_LED_Init(LED3);
  /* Initialize DFSDM channels and filter for record */
  DFSDM_Init();

  /* Initialize playback */
  Playback_Init();

  /* Start DFSDM conversions */
  if(HAL_OK != HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(&DfsdmRightFilterHandle, RightRecBuff, SizeBuff))
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if(HAL_OK != HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegularStart_DMA(&DfsdmLeftFilterHandle, LeftRecBuff, SizeBuff))
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  osThreadDef(Audio1, Audio_Thread, osPriorityHigh, 0, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE);

   /* Thread 2 definition */
   osThreadDef(SD1, SD_Thread, osPriorityNormal, 0, configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE);

   /* Start thread 1 */
   AudioThreadHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Audio1), NULL);

   /* Start thread 2 */
   SDThreadHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(SD1), NULL);

   /* Start scheduler */
   osKernelStart();
   for(;;);


}

static void SD_Thread(void const *argument)
{

  uint32_t i, byteswritten;                     // File write/read counts /

  BSP_LED_On(LED3);
  //##-1- Link the micro SD disk I/O driver ##################################/
  if(FATFS_LinkDriver(&SD_Driver, SDPath) == 0)
  {
    //##-2- Register the file system object to the FatFs module ##############/
    if(f_mount(&SDFatFs, (TCHAR const*)SDPath, 0) != FR_OK)
    {
      // FatFs Initialization Error
      Error_Handler();
    }
    else
    {
      //##-3- Create a FAT file system (format) on the logical drive #########/
      // WARNING: Formatting the uSD card will delete all content on the device /
      if(f_mkfs((TCHAR const*)SDPath, 0, 0) != FR_OK)
      {
        // FatFs Format Error /
        Error_Handler();
      }
      else
      {
        //##-4- Create and Open a new text file object with write access #####/
        if(f_open(&MyFile, "STM32.TXT", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) != FR_OK)
        {
          // 'STM32.TXT' file Open for write Error /
          Error_Handler();
        }
        else
        {
            BSP_LED_On(LED1);
          //##-5- Write data to the text file ################################/
            for(i=0; i<2*SizeBuff; i++ )
                f_printf(&MyFile,"%d ", PlayBuff[i]);
            f_close(&MyFile);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


static void Audio_Thread(void const *argument)
{
    uint32_t i, count;
    BSP_LED_On(LED1);
    while(1)
      {
        if((DmaLeftRecHalfBuffCplt == 1) && (DmaRightRecHalfBuffCplt == 1))
        {
          /* Store values on Play buff */
          for(i = 0; i < SizeBuff/2; i++)
          {
            PlayBuff[2*i]     = SaturaLH((LeftRecBuff[i] >> 8), -32768, 32767);
            PlayBuff[(2*i)+1] = SaturaLH((RightRecBuff[i] >> 8), -32768, 32767);
          }
          if(PlaybackStarted == 0)
          {
            if(0 != audio_drv->Play(AUDIO_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint16_t *) &PlayBuff[0], 4096))
            {
              Error_Handler();
            }
            if(HAL_OK != HAL_SAI_Transmit_DMA(&SaiHandle, (uint8_t *) &PlayBuff[0], 4096))
            {
              Error_Handler();
            }
            PlaybackStarted = 1;
          }
          DmaLeftRecHalfBuffCplt  = 0;
          DmaRightRecHalfBuffCplt = 0;
        }
        if((DmaLeftRecBuffCplt == 1) && (DmaRightRecBuffCplt == 1))
        {
          /* Store values on Play buff */
          for(i = SizeBuff/2; i < SizeBuff; i++)
          {
            PlayBuff[2*i]     = SaturaLH((LeftRecBuff[i] >> 8), -32768, 32767);
            PlayBuff[(2*i)+1] = SaturaLH((RightRecBuff[i] >> 8), -32768, 32767);
          }
          DmaLeftRecBuffCplt  = 0;
          DmaRightRecBuffCplt = 0;  
          osThreadResume(SDThreadHandle);
          osThreadSuspend(NULL);
         }
        }
}
```

Comment: have you ever program this micro (or any other). If not start  from the basic stuff, not this quite complicated task

Comment: Well I have done some basic things, like thread creation, hello world with gui etc, and other examples. This is a project which is included in my course